# How do I create a Site SObject via reflection

Tags: apex

```
System.Type siteType = Type.forName('Site');
Site newSite = (Site) siteType.newInstance();
```

This fails with the error: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type System.Site to Site

Reflection works in most cases for creating a new instance of an SObject, but in cases where there is also a system class with the same name we get that instead of the SObject.  Is it possible to create a new instance of a Site SObject via reflection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually two Site objects, one in System and one in Schema. The former has a bunch of static methods like changePassword and createExternalUser, while the latter represents the sObject Site you're looking for. To get at *that* one, use its full name:

```
Type sitesObjectType = Type.forName('Schema.Site');
Site siteRecord = (Site)sitesObjectType.newInstance();
```

Comment: Perfect.  In retrospect I should have been able to guess the namespace.